# Using custom font without including in info.plist ios

Tags: ios, fonts, customization

In iOS if we want to use a custom font we have to include the `font.ttf` in app bundle and add the `font.ttf` as a value to font key in the **info.plist** file.

I want to use a custom font whose ttf file will be downloaded from my server after the application is installed in the device.

1: Is it possible to use that font in my application

2: If yes how can I use that font?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
NSData *inData = /* your decrypted font-file data */;
CFErrorRef error;
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &error)) {
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
} else {
    CFStringRef fontNameRef = CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:(__bridge NSString *)fontNameRef size:someSize];
    // Your UIFont is ready.

    CFRelease(fontNameRef);
}
CFRelease(fontRef);
CFRelease(provider);
```

> You can load a font this way at any time during your app’s execution, and it immediately becomes available in `UIFont` and `UIWebView` (via regular `font-family` CSS declarations, no `@font-face` required) just as if it had been declared in `UIAppFonts`.

[Source](http://www.marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading)

**Note:** You should include `CoreText` to have `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` be available.

Comment: @renefi great answer... just checked and verified.. thanks very much. Note: - font should relpace with fontref

Comment: @jjpp Yes, I have corrected them. Thanks for pointing it out!