# How to reuse fonts in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Imagine I have this custom font
    font.ttf

And I have two projects. Project A in `/projects/A` and project B in `/projects/B`

I don't want to copy paste this font among projects.

I created a cocoa touch framework and added the `font.ttf` to that. Then reused that framework in projects A and B. But it doesn't work. Is it possible?

Comment: Good question - so the font is included in the Framework ?

Comment: The font in your framework probably have it's own bundle and plist, so you can't add it to your plist I think, might as well try the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412068/using-custom-font-without-including-in-info-plist-ios)

Comment: yes, it's included in the framework. @Fattie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [thread](https://www.jarroo.com/blog/2017/2/20/loading-custom-fonts-programmatically-in-swift), you can try

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "frameworkIdentifier")!

let url =  bundle.url(forResource: "fontName", withExtension: "ttf")!

if let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: url as CFURL) {
    let font = CGFont(dataProvider)
    print(font)
}
```

//

[image]

//

[image]